# Adding basic auth headers to all the requests in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring boot application development.
I need to add the basic auth headers to all the api requests in spring boot.
Can any one share the valid documentation of how I proceed

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of auth u require
for something like self auth token it would look something like

```
public String controllerFunction(@RequestHeader("Auth-header") String authToken){

    if (authToken == null) {
        log.error("Self token authentication failed");
        throw new Exception(TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    if (!"auth_password".equals(authToken)) {
        log.error("Self token authentication failed");
        throw new Exception(AUTH_FAILED);
    }
    log.info("Self token authentication successful");
}
```

If it's unique to individual users u will have to fetch the "auth_password" from your database for that particular user and validate it

To use it in globally you can build annotations like this

```
@Before("@annotation(tokenValidation)")
public void beforeAdvice(TokenValidation tokenValidation) {
   String authToken = request.getHeader("Auth-header");
   if (authToken == null) {
      log.error("Self token authentication failed");
      throw new Exception(TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);
   }

   if (!"auth_password".equals(authToken)) {
      log.error("Self token authentication failed");
      throw new Exception(AUTH_FAILED);
   }
   log.info("Self token authentication successful");
}
```

U might have to look up how to implement the annotations in spring boot but this is a basic concept.

and in the controllers, u just have to do

```
@tokenValidation
public String controllerFunction(String authToken){
   //your code;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Is there any way to add this Authorization header for few request globally?
so that I can avoid having redundant code

Comment: I have edited the original answer so that it's easier for other people looking for answers.